# Add keyboard support and backspace to jQuery calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calculator

How to add simple keyboard support to calculator and backspace functionality to delete last entered numbers (if number > 1) or `.` symbol? Also I need to use `.` and `,` symbols at the same time for doing something like this `(1.02 + 1,02 = 2.04)`.

Here is full code:

```js
// Calculator script

$(function() {

  // Main variables
  var $screen = $('.screen');
  var value = 0;
  var start = true;
  var action = 0;

  // Display '0' on load
  $screen.text('0');

  // Digits
  $('.digit').on('click', function() {
    var mytext = $(this).text();
    var curtext = (start) ? '0' : $screen.text();
    start = false;
    if (mytext == '.') {
      if (curtext.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    } else {
      if (curtext === '0') {
        // Overwrite
        $screen.text(mytext);
      } else {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    }
  });

  // Maths operations
  function Maths_operations() {
    var num = parseFloat($screen.text());
    switch (action) {
      case 0:
        { // Nothing?
          value = num;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        { // Add
          value += num;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        { // Subtract
          value -= num;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        { // Multiply
          value *= num;
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        { // Divide
          if (num == 0) {
            value = 'Error'; // Couldn't divide by zero!
          } else {
            value /= num;
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        break; // Shouldn't happen...
    }
    start = true; // New number now...
  }

  // Actions
  $('.action').on('click', function() {
    switch ($(this).text()) {
      case 'C':
        { // Clear
          value = 0;
          $screen.text('0');
          action = 0;
          start = true;
        }
        break;
      case '←':
        { // Delete last
          Maths_operations();
          action = 5;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00F7':
        { // Divide
          Maths_operations();
          action = 4;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00D7':
        { // Multiply
          Maths_operations();
          action = 3;
        }
        break;
      case '-':
        { // Subtract
          Maths_operations();
          action = 2;
        }
        break;
      case '+':
        { // Add
          Maths_operations();
          action = 1;
        }
        break;
      case '=':
        { // Equals
          Maths_operations();
          $screen.text(value);
          action = 0; // Nothing
        }
        break;
      default:
        { // If it's not a button
          console.log($(this).text());
        }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* Basic reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* Global text styling */
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Background */
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(171, 168, 168, 0.82);
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Name */
.pre-top > span {
  display: block;
  
  /* Special text styling */
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', Monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.pre-top .version {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Calculator body */
.calculator {
  
  /* Absolute horizontal & vertical centering */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 9px;
  background: #b8c6cc;
  background: linear-gradient(#979fa2 14.9%, #6a7073 52.31%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  /* Using box shadows to create 3D effects */
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5e6264, 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Top */
.top span.clear {
  float: left;
}

.top .screen {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* Inset shadow on the screen to create some indent */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Clear floats */
.keys,
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Applying same to the keys */
.keys span,
.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 11px 0;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
 
  /* Smoothing out hover and active states using css3 transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  /* Prevent selection of text inside keys in all browsers*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.keys span {
  width: 84px;
}

/* Style different type of keys (operators/evaluate/clear) differently */
.keys span.operator {
  background: #f5ac75;
  /* Remove right margins from operator keys */
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.keys span.eval {
  background: #79de9e;
  color: #fff;
}

.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  background: #e79199;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Some hover effects */
.keys span:hover {
  background: #7d8ae3;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5963a0;
  color: #fff;
}

.keys span.operator:hover {
  background: #fa9345;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #ce8248;
}

.keys span.eval:hover {
  background: #39f788;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #2fc66e;
  color: #fff;
}

.top span.clear:hover,
.top span.backspace:hover {
  background: #f86670;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #d5656d;
}

/* Simulating "pressed" effect on active state of the keys by removing the box-shadow and moving the keys down a bit */
.keys span:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #6b54d3;
}

.keys span.eval:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #717a33;
}

.top span.clear:active,
.top span.backspace:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #d3545d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Some Google Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab|Roboto+Mono:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Calculator -->
<div class="calculator">

  <!-- Name -->
  <div class="pre-top">
    <span class="name">jQuery calculator</span>
    <span class="version">v1.1</span>
  <div>

  <!-- Clear key & screen-->
  <div class="top">
    <span class="action clear">C</span>
    <span class="action backspace">←</span>
    <span class="screen"></span>
  </div>

  <!-- Operators and other keys -->
  <div class="keys">
    <span class="digit">7</span>
    <span class="digit">8</span>
    <span class="digit">9</span>
    <span class="action operator">+</span>
    <span class="digit">4</span>
    <span class="digit">5</span>
    <span class="digit">6</span>
    <span class="action operator">-</span>
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">2</span>
    <span class="digit">3</span>
    <span class="action operator">&divide;</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">.</span>
    <span class="action eval">=</span>
    <span class="action operator">&times;</span>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

and [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvzqrL) version. Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 1):

When I added shortcut keys to a web application, I ended up using jwerty. I used it with jQuery but it has no dependencies.

https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty

It makes it easy to specify the key and the event handler.

```
jwerty.key('⌫', function () {
    //Code here to remove last char from calculator screen
});
```

Note: You will have to make sure the browser window has focus for key shortcuts to work.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I need simple example without using any libraries or something similar.

Comment: Try this fork of your pen to add backspace: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvzgNQ

You'll probably want to check if the screen has a value before updating it.The other buttons will be similar.

Comment: Something went wrong when I'm trying to delete number 1.023 and when it should delete `.` it deletes  full `1.0`. What's the point? Also it starts deleting after 2 click on button...

Answer (score 1):

I tried this snippet and works fine.
The action of backspace is captured but actually is not implemented also in mouse keyboard.

```
$( "body" ).keydown(function( event ) {

  if ( event.which == 13 || event.which == 8) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }

    var input= mapKey(event.which);
    if(input == undefined)return;
    var mytext = input;


    var curtext = (start) ? '0' : $screen.text();
    start = false;
    if (mytext == '.' || mytext == ',' ) {
      if (curtext.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    } else {
      if (curtext === '0') {
        // Overwrite
        $screen.text(mytext);
      } else if(jQuery.isNumeric(mytext)) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    }
   console.log(mytext);
    switch (mytext) {

  case 'c':
    { // Clear
      value = 0;
      $screen.text('0');
      action = 0;
      start = true;
    }
    break;
  case '←':
    { // Delete last
      Maths_operations();
      action = 5;
    }
    break;
  case '\u00F7':
    { // Divide
      Maths_operations();
      action = 4;
    }
    break;
  case '\u00D7':
    { // Multiply
      Maths_operations();
      action = 3;
    }
    break;
  case '-':
    { // Subtract
      Maths_operations();
      action = 2;
    }
    break;
  case '+':
    { // Add
      Maths_operations();
      action = 1;
    }
    break;
  case '=':      
    { // Equals
      Maths_operations();
      $screen.text(value);
      action = 0; // Nothing
    }
    break;
  default:
    { // If it's not a button
     // console.log($(this).text());
    }
}
function mapKey(myKey){
    switch(myKey){
      case 48:
      case 96:
      return "0";
      case 49:
      case 97:
      return "1";
      case 50:
      case 98:
      return "2";
      case 51:
      case 99:
      return "3";
      case 52:
      case 100:
      return "4";
      case 53:
      case 101:
      return "5";
      case 54:
      case 102:
      return "6";
      case 55:
      case 103:
      return "7";
      case 56:
      case 104:
      return "8";
      case 57:
      case 105:
      return "9";
      case 67:
      return "c";
      case 8:
      return '←';
      case 13:
      case 187:
      return '=';
      case 109:
      return '-';
      case 107:
      return '+';
      case 111:
      return '\u00F7';
      case 106:
      return '\u00D7';
      case 188:
      case 190:
      return '.';

    }
  }
  //$(this).text().append("");
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it's not working, how do you use it?

Comment: http://cesare.heliohost.org/calc/
it works in this address?
I have tried with firefox and chrome, and seems work.
I didn't implements the function for delete.

Comment: Yes, it works, but not fin,  because it changes numbers with maths operators and sometimes not all numbers works...

Comment: I fixed the problem related the numbers, and now you can use all numbers and operators without affect the screen element.
You can check on 
http://cesare.heliohost.org/calc
and is possible to download also  for implement other feature.
http://cesare.heliohost.org/calc/calc.zip

Comment: Now math operations throught keyboard not working, also I need 'delete' functionality and more clean code as it possible.

Comment: but keylock there is in keyboard indipendently of OS, more references of key code can be found on:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Refresh helps, can you please clear the code, I think it has a lot of similar staff, also I need working backspace functionality.